# Show that the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: |x-y| \leq 2\}$ is not bounded.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

im new on math and I'm trying to prove that the following set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R^2}: |x-y| \leq 2\}$ is not bounded. This is my argument and I just need someone else's aprove.

My definition is

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R^2}$, we say that, for $A\not = \emptyset$, $A$ is bounded if $\exists M>0$ s.t. $\forall \bar{a} \in A$, $||\bar{a}|| \leq M$.

Proof.

Let $M\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $M>0$. Let $\bar{a}=(2M, 2M)$ thus $|2M-2M|=0 \leq 2$, then $\bar{a} \in A$ and $A \not = \emptyset$. We have that $||\bar{a}|| = \sqrt{4M^2+4M^2} = \sqrt{8}M$ which is clearly greater than $M$, that is to say $||\bar{a}||>M$.

Therefore, $A$ is a non bounded set.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Yep.... that's correct.  Don't need $a = (2M,2M)$ tough.  Simply having $a =(M,M)$ with $|a| = \sqrt 2 M > M$ would work just as well.  ... Alteratively noting $(k,k+2)\in A$ for all $k$ but $|(k,k+2)| = \sqrt {2k^2 + 4k + 4}> |k|$ is clearly unbounded.

Comment: Thanks you so much @fleablood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another practical way is to take an unbounded sequence of $A$, say,
$$(x_n,y_n)=(n,n), \quad n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: Then to proof that this sequence has no limit, right?

Comment: The limit is $\infty$. If you take limit in your definition you get $M\ge \infty$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: beautiful proof man! thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it's good for you.

Comment: I think showing that the sequence  $\{(n,n)\}$ is unbounded is no easier than showing the original set $A$ is unbounded.

Comment: It is obvious that $\|(n,n)\| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: I cannot mark it as accepted. I don't have enought reputation :( Sorry bro

Answer (score 1):

Very good demonstration! ButThe only detail I see is that:
\begin{equation*}
||\bar{a}|| = \sqrt{4M^2 + 4M^2} = 2\sqrt{2}M,
\end{equation*}
but anyway it is true that $||\bar{a}|| > M.$

Comment: Yeah bro! i saw my mistake! ggg thank you so much